# How to get error object? when use member function in deadline_timer

Tags: boost, timer, boost-asio

I use boost::asio::deadline_timer using a member function as a handler (callback function).

If I cancel a timer, how to get error object in print() member function?

```
class printer
{
public:
    printer(boost::asio::io_service& io)
        : timer_(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1)),
          count_(0)
    {
        timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print, this));
    }
    ~printer()
    {
        std::cout << "Final count is " << count_ << "\n";
    }
    void print()
    {
        if (count_ < 5)
        {
            std::cout << count_ << "\n";
            ++count_;

            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print, this));
        }
    }

private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
    int count_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    printer p(io);
    io.run();

    return 0;
}
```

I try to set error object using bind in async_wait(), but it's compile error

```
timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Comment: You didn't supply the compiler error message. This is strange, since you have a question about it.

Comment: @sehe THANK YOU :) I wrote a wrong member function signature like void print(boost::system::error_code ec). const keyword is omitted.   and, I must write error message next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your method signature matches, it should be no problem:

```
void print(boost::system::error_code const ec)

// and

boost::bind(&printer::print, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error)
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8629f0a7a7dec60)**:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class printer
{
public:
    printer(boost::asio::io_service& io)
        : timer_(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1)),
          count_(0)
    {
        timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    ~printer()
    {
        std::cout << "Final count is " << count_ << "\n";
    }

    void print(boost::system::error_code const ec)
    {
        if (ec)
            std::cout << "Error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        if (count_ < 5)
        {
            std::cout << count_ << "\n";
            ++count_;

            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }

private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
    int count_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    printer p(io);
    io.run();
}
```